# Use results from a query into the SELECT list

Tags: postgresql

I would like to select all columns of a table except one.

My first step was to follow the example given in this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115315). With something as such:

```sql
 SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ' ORDER BY attnum)
 FROM pg_attribute
 WHERE attrelid = 'public.my_table'::regclass
   AND NOT attisdropped
   AND attnum > 0
   AND attname <> 'bad_column'
```

This produces a string, as expected. But now I want to use this to query the rows of my table.
If we call the result from above `subset_columns`, then I would like to make the query:

```sql
SELECT subset_columns
FROM my_table
LIMIT 10;
```

But I am not sure how to generate this `subset_columns` variable, and if this style of query is even possible in postgresql?

Comment: you cannot dynamically select columns in mysql

Comment: however you can use that result in condition as a subquery.

Comment: if you can give me enough context on what you want to achieve, I can solve your problem

Comment: I want to select all rows for all, except one, column.

Comment: why don't you write down all the columns name on select statement except that column

Comment: I like your pragmatic approach :) I just didn't want to follow this since our table has 40+ columns and new columns are likely added every 2-3 weeks.
But that's a whole other problem.

Comment: best way is to stick with pragmatic approach :) I didn't see any other option. you guys should normalize your database, We usually stay consistent with database.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in PostgreSQL. You can do it only in pl/PgSQL (or other pl/*), but not in plain SQL and only if you want to store values on temporary table.
Below you will find how you can create a variable pl/PgSQL:

```
WITH subset_columns AS (
      SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ' ORDER BY attnum)
       FROM pg_attribute
       WHERE attrelid = 'public.my_table'::regclass
       AND NOT attisdropped
       AND attnum > 0
       AND attname <> 'bad_column'
)
```

I suggest you to create a view instead of variable, and you select all the desired columns except the one you dont want to export. So it will be simple to re-use it whenever you want.